# Android XML Layout autosize

Tags: android, xml, layout, resolution

I'm going crazy for setting up a layout in XML for Android that shows four rectangular images, two per row, properly on different displays.
Can anyone help me?
The best I could get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp" />
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.45">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img1"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45" />
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.1" />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.45">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img3"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45" />
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/img4"
                    android:layout_weight="0.45" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to have a layout similar to Windows Phone's Tiles...
It is correct to use the attribute "layout_weight" for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is a [Gridview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

And then if you add four items to the adapter that connects to the gridview, you will end up with your desired UI.

```
    protected ArrayAdapter<Item> provideAdapterView() {
        return new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getActivity(), R.layout.item){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(view==null) {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                //perform whatever you want to the layout that is inflated in the item file.
                return view;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public View performOnCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        adapter = provideAdapterView();
        GridView gridView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```